# Property "CDbCriteria.:centerId" is not defined in yii

Tags: yii, yii1.x

I am using select method in yii it gives error "Property "CDbCriteria.:centerId" is not defined"

```
if (0 < self::model()->countByAttributes(
    'centerId = :centerId AND qTypeId = :qTypeId',
    array(
        ':centerId' => $centerId,
        ':qTypeId'  => $qTypeId,
    )
)) {
    throw new Exception('Duplicate Entry for center and que type');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this method in a wrong way. You skipped first argument, which should be list of active record arguments used as filter ([see documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#countByAttributes-detail)). You probably need something like:

```
if (0 < self::model()->countByAttributes([
    'centerId' => $centerId,
    'qTypeId'  => $qTypeId,
]) {
    throw new Exception('Duplicate Entry for center and que type');
}
```

Or use [`count()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#count-detail):

```
if (0 < self::model()->count(
    'centerId = :centerId AND qTypeId = :qTypeId',
    [
        ':centerId' => $centerId,
        ':qTypeId'  => $qTypeId,
    ]
)) {
    throw new Exception('Duplicate Entry for center and que type');
}
```